# Add an email address in an Outlook profile

Tags: powershell, email, outlook, addition, profile

I am looking for a solution to add an email address in a newly created Outlook profile using PowerShell

Here is my code to create a brand new profile :

```
$reg="HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles"
$GetDate = Get-Date -Format dd-MM-yyyy
New-Item -Name "outlook_$GetDate" -Path $reg -Force -Verbose
```

What command line should I use after my code to add the email address to the "outlook_$GetDate" profile ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You need to use Outlook COM to do this since it is a setting only available from there. [There are lots of examples of using PowerShell to interop with OL all over the web and on Youtube. Use your favorite search engine to find that](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=PowerShell+%27create+outlook+profile%27&t=h_&ia=web).

Comment: Are you trying to create a new Outlook profile and configure it?

Comment: '@Dmitry Streblechenko' The link I provided has several hits which show how to create OL profiles with code samples.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Yes I am looking for a command line to add the email address in the newly created profile